# Symfony 5 Embed Collection - prototype form not persisted

Tags: php, symfony, collections, symfony-forms, symfony5

I'm trying for many hours to persist my embed collections in the DB. It doesn't work and even do something different.
I have a entity User OneToMany with the entity Address.
I successfully have the embed form but I cannot save it in the DB.
Even worse, when I add the property by_reference => false to my embed field, it delete the existing address I had :/ .
I don't know what I do wrong.
I tried to add the setAdress to my User entity but it's not helping.
I tried to add the Cascade persist but also not working.
It's probably an issue with my controller (**edit_profil**) but I don't see which one.

<strike>I'm now getting the error *Could not determine access type for property "address" in class "App\Entity\User".*</strike>

**UPDATE1**
with the by_reference set to false, I have this error now : *Expected argument of type "App\Entity\Address or null", "instance of Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection" given at property path "address".*
**UPDATE2**
I removed the setter because I have the add and remove method. I also used plural and singural for address as it's done with tag in the documentation.
Now I see the form address is not sent.(it even delete the existing one)
[image]
(I remove in the code what's not necessary)
Here are my files :

RegistrationFormType

```
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\IsTrue;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Symfony\Component\Form\CallbackTransformer;


class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('roles',ChoiceType::class,[
                'choices'=>[
                'Specialist'=>'Role_Specialist',
                'Parent'=>'Role_Parent',
                'Center'=>'Role_Center',],
                'label'=>"Je m'inscris en tant que"])
            ->add('name')
      //...//
            ->add('addresses',CollectionType::class,[
                'entry_type' => AddressType::class,
                'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' =>false,


            ])
        ;
```

User Entity :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="There is already an account with this email")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

//...//

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Address::class, mappedBy="user", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $addresses;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->category = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->schedules = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->bookings = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->addresses = new ArrayCollection();
    }
//...//

/**
 * @return Collection|Addresses[]
 */
public function getAddresses(): Collection
{
    return $this->addresses;
}


public function addAddress(Address $address): self
{
    $address->setUser($this);

    $this->adresse->add($address);
//    if (!$this->addresses->contains($address)) {
//        $this->addresses[] = $address;
//        $address->setUser($this);
//    }
    return $this;
}

public function removeAddress(Address $address): self
{
    if ($this->addresses->removeElement($address)) {
        // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
        if ($address->getUser() === $this) {
            $address->setUser(null);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}

}
```

Registration Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Address;
use App\Entity\User;
use App\Form\AddressType;
use App\Form\RegistrationFormType;
use App\Security\EmailVerifier;
use App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Mime\TemplatedEmail;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\GuardAuthenticatorHandler;
use SymfonyCasts\Bundle\VerifyEmail\Exception\VerifyEmailExceptionInterface;

class RegistrationController extends AbstractController
{
    private $emailVerifier;

    public function __construct(EmailVerifier $emailVerifier)
    {
        $this->emailVerifier = $emailVerifier;
    }

//...//
    /**
     * @Route("/profil/{id}", name="edit_account")
     */
    public function editUser(Request $request,int $id)
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        //Récupération de l'entité User avec l'ID passé et création du formulaire
        $repoUser = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(User::class);
        $user = $repoUser->findOneBy([
            'id'=>$id,
        ]);
        $form = $this->createForm(RegistrationFormType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);


        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $entityManager->persist($user);
            $entityManager->flush();
            $this->addFlash('success', 'User Created! Knowledge is power!');
            return $this->redirectToRoute('edit_account',[
                'id'=>$id,
            ]);
        }
        return $this->render('profil/edit_profil.html.twig', [
            'registrationForm' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
    /**
     * @Route("/verify/email", name="app_verify_email")
     */
    public function verifyUserEmail(Request $request): Response
    {
        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY');

        // validate email confirmation link, sets User::isVerified=true and persists
        try {
            $this->emailVerifier->handleEmailConfirmation($request, $this->getUser());
        } catch (VerifyEmailExceptionInterface $exception) {
            $this->addFlash('verify_email_error', $exception->getReason());

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_register');
        }

        // @TODO Change the redirect on success and handle or remove the flash message in your templates
        $this->addFlash('success', 'Your email address has been verified.');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_register');
    }

}
```

Address Entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\AddressRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=AddressRepository::class)
 */
class Address
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $housenumber;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=10, nullable=true)
     */
    private $additional_info;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $street;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Schedule::class, mappedBy="address_fk")
     */
    private $schedules;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float", nullable=true)
     */
    private $latitude;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float", nullable=true)
     */
    private $longitude;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $city;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $region;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $country;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $postalcode;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="addresses")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->schedules = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getType(): ?string
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    public function setType(string $type): self
    {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getHousenumber(): ?int
    {
        return $this->housenumber;
    }

    public function setHousenumber(int $housenumber): self
    {
        $this->housenumber = $housenumber;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAdditionalInfo(): ?string
    {
        return $this->additional_info;
    }

    public function setAdditionalInfo(?string $additional_info): self
    {
        $this->additional_info = $additional_info;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStreet(): ?string
    {
        return $this->street;
    }

    public function setStreet(string $street): self
    {
        $this->street = $street;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Schedule[]
     */
    public function getSchedules(): Collection
    {
        return $this->schedules;
    }

    public function addSchedule(Schedule $schedule): self
    {
        if (!$this->schedules->contains($schedule)) {
            $this->schedules[] = $schedule;
            $schedule->setAddressFk($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeSchedule(Schedule $schedule): self
    {
        if ($this->schedules->removeElement($schedule)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($schedule->getAddressFk() === $this) {
                $schedule->setAddressFk(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLatitude(): ?float
    {
        return $this->latitude;
    }

    public function setLatitude(?float $latitude): self
    {
        $this->latitude = $latitude;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLongitude(): ?float
    {
        return $this->longitude;
    }

    public function setLongitude(?float $longitude): self
    {
        $this->longitude = $longitude;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCity(): ?string
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    public function setCity(string $city): self
    {
        $this->city = $city;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRegion(): ?string
    {
        return $this->region;
    }

    public function setRegion(?string $region): self
    {
        $this->region = $region;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCountry(): ?string
    {
        return $this->country;
    }

    public function setCountry(string $country): self
    {
        $this->country = $country;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPostalcode(): ?string
    {
        return $this->postalcode;
    }

    public function setPostalcode(?string $postalcode): self
    {
        $this->postalcode = $postalcode;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUser(): ?User
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function setUser(?User $user): self
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Edit_profil Twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{#{% macro niceForm(address) %}#}
{#    <div class="form-group col-md-4">{{ form_row(address.type) }}</div>#}
{#    <div class="form-row">#}
{#        <div class="form-group col-md-4">{{ form_row(address.street) }}</div>#}
{#        <div class="form-group col-md-4">{{ form_row(address.housenumber) }}</div>#}
{#        <div class="form-group col-md-4">{{ form_row(address.additional_info) }}</div>#}
{#    </div>#}
{#    <div class="form-row">#}
{#        <div class="form-group col-md-3">{{ form_row(address.postalcode) }}</div>#}
{#        <div class="form-group col-md-3">{{ form_row(address.city) }}</div>#}
{#        <div class="form-group col-md-3">{{ form_row(address.region) }}</div>#}
{#        <div class="form-group col-md-3">{{ form_row(address.country) }}</div>#}
{#    </div>#}
{#{% endmacro %}#}
{#{% import _self as formMacros %}#}
{% block title %}Edit Profil{% endblock %}
{% block body %}

    {% for flashError in app.flashes('verify_email_error') %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">{{ flashError }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="container">
    {{ form_start(registrationForm) }}
    <div class="form-group">{{ form_row(registrationForm.roles) }}</div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">{{ form_row(registrationForm.name) }}</div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">{{ form_row(registrationForm.firstname) }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">{{ form_row(registrationForm.email) }}</div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">{{ form_row(registrationForm.plainPassword, {
                label: 'Password'
            }) }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">{{ form_row(registrationForm.prefix) }}</div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">{{ form_row(registrationForm.phone) }}</div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">{{ form_row(registrationForm.NISS, {label: 'NISS'}) }}</div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">{{ form_row(registrationForm.BCE, {label: 'BCE'}) }}</div>
    </div>
    </div>
{#        @TODO formatter pour qu'on differencie bien les addresses entre elles par block. Cf block en dessous#}
    <div class="container">

        <h3>Addresses</h3>


        <ul class="addresses" data-index="{{ registrationForm.addresses|length > 0 ? registrationForm.addresses|last.vars.name + 1 : 0 }}" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(registrationForm.addresses.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">
            {% for address in registrationForm.addresses %}
            <li>{{ form_row(address.type) }}</li>
                <li>{{ form_row(address.street) }}</li>
                <li>{{ form_row(address.housenumber) }}</li>
                <li>{{ form_row(address.additional_info) }}</li>

                <li>{{ form_row(address.postalcode) }}</li>
                <li>{{ form_row(address.city) }}</li>
                <li>{{ form_row(address.region) }}</li>
                <li>{{ form_row(address.country) }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>

        <button type="button" class="add_item_link" data-collection-holder-class="addresses">Add an address</button>

        <button type="submit" id="submitRegister" class="btn">Register</button>

        {{ form_end(registrationForm) }}

    </div>
    <script>
        const addFormToCollection = (e) => {
            const collectionHolder = document.querySelector('.' + e.currentTarget.dataset.collectionHolderClass);

            const item = document.createElement('li');

            item.innerHTML = collectionHolder
                .dataset
                .prototype
                .replace(
                    /__name__/g,
                    collectionHolder.dataset.index
                );

            collectionHolder.appendChild(item);

            collectionHolder.dataset.index++;
        };
        document
            .querySelectorAll('.add_item_link')
            .forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener("click", addFormToCollection));

    </script>
```

I hope one of you will able to see what issue I have :)

Thank you

Comment: You do not need to instantiate the `AddressType` form, since it is embedded in the `RegistrationType` form and rendered in your template from `form_row(address.type)`, Remove `$formAddress = $this->createForm(AddressType::class, $address);` and all references to it. Then add the address to the `User` in your controller `$user->addAddress($address)`. Also your `setAdress(?Adress $adress):` reference needs to utilize the collection`$this->address = new ArrayCollection($address ?? [])`, though I recommend removing that method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I notice something confusing in my question. The function rendering my edit_profil twig is editUser. The first function is used for the registration of user the first time and is where I instantiate the AdresseType. The idea was to have one form with only one adress to fill in. 
My question was more for the editUser in fact.  Sorry for the confusion and thanks for the quick answer !

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Thanks for your help Will B. I was able to solve my problem which was coming from my controller. I used what was explained in the doc (the 11th reading was the right one).
In https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html, the persistence doctrine point was very useful (and it's not just for the remove, nice lesson), I just had to add a setUser for my addresses in the loop.
Mea culpa and thanks again !
Here is my controller:

```
/**
     * @Route("/profil/{id}", name="edit_account")
     */
    public function editUser(Request $request,int $id)
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        //Récupération de l'entité User avec l'ID passé et création du formulaire
        $repoUser = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(User::class);
        $user = $repoUser->findOneBy([
            'id'=>$id,
        ]);
        $form = $this->createForm(RegistrationFormType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $originalAddresses = new ArrayCollection();

        // Create an ArrayCollection of the current Tag objects in the database
        foreach ($user->getAddresses() as $address) {
            $address->setUser($user);
            $originalAddresses->add($address);
        }
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            foreach ($originalAddresses as $address) {
                if (false === $user->getAddresses()->contains($address)) {
                    // remove the Task from the Tag
                    $address->getUser()->removeElement($user);

                    // if it was a many-to-one relationship, remove the relationship like this
                    // $tag->setTask(null);

                    $entityManager->persist($address);
                }
            }
                }
        $entityManager->persist($user);
        $entityManager->flush();
        return $this->render('profil/edit_profil.html.twig', [
            'registrationForm' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

Thanks again !